# Open source RTMP streaming

Tags: streaming, rtmp

I am trying to do the following:

PC 1 - Small computer in an office
A webcam output is captured by ffmpeg and ffmpeg outputs an RTMP stream.

PC 2 - Fast computer, > 1 GBPS bandwidth
The PC grabs the stream and makes it available to the world

Website
Using JWPlayer, each visitor's client is pulling the stream from PC 2.

I looked at a few commercial solutions (wowza, etc) but I am thinking there may be an open source way to do this as well. I stumbled across OBS studio, but I don't know yet if it is capable to do it.

btw, the high bandwidth server has to be Windows.

Comment: Ffmpeg + nginx on computer 2. That’s all you need.

Comment: is nginx now working properly on windows? years ago it didn't and I kind of forgot about it since then

Comment: Beats me. I haven’t touched windows in 15 years. If nginx doesn’t work, substitute a lesser http server.